# Trying to use Datatrigger with enum and getting enum "..does not exist in namespace"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, enums

I am using WPF and trying to change my image source based on property defined as the enum

The xaml looks like the following:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogoCam;assembly="
    x:Class="LogoCam.MainWindow"
    Title="Logo Cam" Height="600" Width="600"
    Background="Gainsboro"
    SizeChanged="MainWindow_SizeChanged"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    MinHeight="600"
    MinWidth="600"
    Icon="Resources/millcam.ico"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Closed="MainWindow_Closed"
    >
```

I have an image that I want to change based on the value of the enum

```
<Image x:Name="leftImage" Width="180" Height="42" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Play.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="{x:Static local:Modes.Playing}" Binding="{Binding Path=ActionMode}" >
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Stop.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Value="Modes.Stopped" Binding="{Binding Path=ActionMode}" >
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Play.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Value="Modes.SnapShot" Binding="{Binding Path=ActionMode}" >
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Back.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </Image.Style>
 </Image>
```

See the error I'm getting when trying to use it in the xaml "The name "Modes" does not exsit in the namespace 'clr-namespace:LogoCam;assembly=':
[image]

Xaml.cs looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace LogoCam
{

    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public enum Modes { Playing, Stopped, SnapShot };

            private Modes  mode = Modes.Stopped;

            public Modes ActionMode
            {
                private set
                {
                    mode = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ActionMode");
                }
                get
                {
                    return mode;
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = this;

            }

            private void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
    }
}
```

Why is it not finding my enum in the xaml?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the namespace, it's in your class, hence:

```
{x:Static local:MainWindow+Modes.Playing}
```

One of the reasons i avoid defining enums inside classes.

Comment: I get the same thing: The name "MainWindow+Modes" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:LogoCam;assembly=".

Comment: Then `local` is not actually pointing to the correct namespace.

Comment: I also tried moving the enum in and out of the calss before I posted. It didn't work

Comment: I'm not understanding The namspace is LogoCam. Local is pointing to LogoCam. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't even posted the whole code showing the namespace of the file, nor have you mentioned whether this is the executing assembly or not. Have you even tried to run the application?

Comment: If this is just appearing in the editor, then it's a bug in the designer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117435/discussion-between-brian-mcleod-and-h-b).